# How to hide some of the columns in the table when in mobile view?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

this link is for the desktop view [Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44A69.png).
and this link if for the mobile view. [Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap0TP.png).

how to make these columns in the mobile view looks like the columns in the desktop view.

here's my code for the css. by the way im using a gridview for displaying the table.

CSS:

```
    #data {
     display: block;
     margin:20px;
     width:95%;
     height: 400px;
     overflow-y: scroll;
   }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #data td, th {
        display:none;
    }
        #data th:nth-child(1),
        #data td:nth-child(1),
        #data th:nth-child(4),
        #data td:nth-child(4),
        #data th:nth-child(14),
        #data td:nth-child(14),
        #data th:nth-child(56),
        #data td:nth-child(56),
        #data th:nth-child(57),
        #data td:nth-child(57),
        #data th:nth-child(66),
        #data td:nth-child(66) {display:block;}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    #data th:nth-child(1),
        #data td:nth-child(1),
        #data th:nth-child(4),
        #data td:nth-child(4),
        #data th:nth-child(14),
        #data td:nth-child(14),
        #data th:nth-child(56),
        #data td:nth-child(56),
        #data th:nth-child(57),
        #data td:nth-child(57),
        #data th:nth-child(66),
        #data td:nth-child(66) {display:block;}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bootstrap in built classes for this scenario like

```
.hidden-xs{
    /*By adding class to the div will be hidden in phones and will be visible in desktop*/
}
```

And for more classes you can refer to this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

Comment: only div will be hidden sir? what if i want to hide a specific column sir? @stanze

Comment: Try adding those class to the respective column and try.

Comment: thank you sir but i want to hide more than 50 columns sir. what if i make it reverse? if i hide it first and make the remaining visible? how can i do that sir? thank you for the help sir @stanze

Comment: you add that class to every column you want to hide

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using some CSS tricks:

Just add `sm-device` class to the columns you want to show resolution below i-pad (`max-width 768px`) , you can change it accordingly in `CSS`

and

Add `xl-device` class to those columns which you want to display on  large screens above `max-width 768px`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .sm-device {opacity:1 !important ; transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, padding 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;}
    
    .xl-device {opacity:0 !important; transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, padding 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;}

}

.xl-device {opacity:1; transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, padding 0.5s ease-in-out 0s; -moz-transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, padding 0.5s ease-in-out 0s; -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, padding 0.5s ease-in-out 0s; }

.sm-device {opacity:0;  transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, padding 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;  -moz-transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, padding 0.5s ease-in-out 0s; -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, padding 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/f1076Lsk/

Comment: How can i apply this in GridView sir? i dont know where to put the class of each column @PHP Worm... ?

Comment: It would be better if you can show me your html, @RigelKentCarbonel

Comment: `<div class="table-responsive">
            <asp:GridView runat="Server" id="data" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive">
                </asp:GridView>


        </div> ` @PHP Worm...